# Working with threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I need to create two threads, one of which will return even numbers and the other will return odd numbers. What am I doing wrong?

[image: here is my console]

[image: Here is a screenshot of my functions]

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD ID1 = 1, ID2 = 100;
    DWORD arr[] = {ID1, ID2};
    HANDLE h[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        h[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &f1, arr, 0, &arr[0]);
        if (h[0] == NULL)
            _tprintf(_T("%d"), GetLastError());
        h[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &f2, arr, 0, &arr[1]);
        if (h[1] == NULL)
            _tprintf(_T("%d"), GetLastError());
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        CloseHandle(h[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, the array `h` only has 1 element, but you try to write to 2 of them.

Comment: You are creating 4 threads, due to the loop. Remove the for loop and change h to 'HANDLE h[2];` to make your array big enough for 2 handles.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed I did. Bad habit I'm afraid.

Comment: Use the [C++11 Thread Support Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) if you can. It provides a very simple threading api which also benefits from being cross-platform.

Comment: Unrelated issues: you are creating 4 threads, but you wait for only 2 threads, and you close only 2 threads. Also the usage of `arr` and `&arr[0]` is confusing and possibly wrong.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. While screenshots can improve the quality of a question, anything that can be represented in plain text usually should be. Screenshots escape text searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
HANDLE h[1];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    h[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &f1, arr, 0, &arr[0]);
    if (h[0] == NULL)
        _tprintf(_T("%d"), GetLastError());
    h[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &f2, arr, 0, &arr[1]);
    if (h[1] == NULL)
        _tprintf(_T("%d"), GetLastError());
}
```

To this

```
HANDLE h[2];
h[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &f1, arr, 0, &arr[0]);
if (h[0] == NULL)
    _tprintf(_T("%d"), GetLastError());
h[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &f2, arr, 0, &arr[1]);
if (h[1] == NULL)
    _tprintf(_T("%d"), GetLastError());
```

- You are creating 2 threads within the body of a for loop which executes twice (AKA 4 threads when you really meant for 2).
- You are attempting to save the handles to these threads into a HANDLE array which can only hold one element.
- On the second execution of the loop, you have overwritten the elements of h[] again, so when you later wait for them to finish and attempt to close the handles, you are not even closing the same handle.
- You need the HANDLE array to be size 2, and you need to remove the first for loop (you are passing the function pointers separately, so there is no way to do this in a loop unless you put the function pointers into an array of the same length as h[]).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why this fixes the issue?

Comment: Please explain the changes, and why the original version causes problems.

Comment: Added explanation. Sorry... new here.